# Should my function take channels as input?

Tags: go

I'm building a go library that manages and writes data to a file. I have written a file writer that I can pass data to, and it'll write that data to the file via a buffered writer. This means that a service using the library will have to call a close method once the service shuts down to write anything still in the buffer. I see two ways of handling this:

1. Expose a `Close` method that the service can use.
2. Use channels. If the service closes the channel, that'll close the buffer in the library. My lib function would look like this:

```
func (r *Repo) Write(ctx context.Context, data <-chan Data, errCh chan<- error) error {
    for doc := range data {
        err := r.file.Write(ctx, doc)
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }

    err = r.file.Close(ctx)
    return err
}
```

My question is if the `Write()` signature make sense, as it takes a receive channel and a send channel for errors as input? I haven't seen similar examples of this. Maybe there is a better way of organising this?

Comment: Publishing and expecting the use of a `Close()` method is pretty common. I don't see why you should make your API use a channel just because you have some clean-up to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. i.e. using `Close` function makes more sense especially if one looks at the go way of doing things.

Also using channels complicates things when  things can be done without them.
Like the `Write` implementation has a for loop which keeps on reading data.

```
    for doc := range data {
        err := r.file.Write(ctx, doc)
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }
```

this means any one calling this write function would get blocked and will need to call this into a goroutine if non-blocking behaviour is required.

Additionally having a simple write signature like:
`func (r *Repo) Write(data Data) error`
looks more clean, and the context can be made a part of `Repo` initialisation if that's not changing each time function is getting called.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I guess I was overthinking the solution. I'm going to stick with the simplest. Makes sense.

Comment: I have done similar overthinking in past. One lesson I learned from looking at libraries is that they should be simple enough that clients can build complex logic around it if required.